# How can I fetch sender info from "update" value

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to get sender information from the 'update' parameter, what is returned from it? I am using the 'python-telegram-bot' package

```
def startBot(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('HI I am ww helper')

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", startBot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a reference to the sender as `update.message.from_user`

```
def startBot(update, context):
    print("USER:", update.message.from_user.first_name)
    update.message.reply_text('HI I am ww helper')
```

You can find the Documentation for `Update` object in the [official API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update) as well as in [the library](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html) for future references.